# Is there no way to constrain the baseline of a label to match the bottom edge of another view?

Tags: ios, uilabel, autolayout, nslayoutconstraint

I have a custom meter view. And a label that shows the numeric value graphed by the meter. Using AutoLayout constraints, I want to align the `baseline` of the label with the `bottom` of the view.

When I <kbd>ctrl</kbd> drag between the two and choose to align bottoms, and then try to use the `Size Inspector` to tune it, it won't give me the option of baseline for the label (just `Top`, `Bottom`, and `Center Y`).

Is there no way to constrain the baseline of a label to match the bottom edge of another view in the Storyboard Editor?

Can I do it in direct code? What would an example of that look like?

Comment: You mean size inspector on the constraint? do you select the constraint then click on size inspector? because when I select that size inspector on the constraint I only get one field says constant?!

Comment: Click the `First Item` or `Second Item` drop down menus. You'll see a list of different constrainable attributes. Baseline is in there, but grayed out.

Comment: when you have two UILabel. select both of them and click the first item. baseline will not be grated. because, both have baseline att.

Comment: I think it must be done programmatically. Interesting question. +1 and favoured. waiting for answer.

Comment: Baseline is applicable for UILabel only.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I determined that the Storyboard Editor just doesn't seem to want to do this directly. You can do it programmatically with something like this:

```
NSLayoutConstraint *constraint = [NSLayoutConstraint
    constraintWithItem: self.myView
    attribute: NSLayoutAttributeBottom
    relatedBy: NSLayoutRelationEqual
    toItem: self.myLabel
    attribute: NSLayoutAttributeBaseline
    multiplier: 1
    constant: 0];
[self.myView.superview addConstraint: constraint];
```

To make the storyboard experience happy, I used a bottom-to-bottom constraint and checked the `Placeholder remove at build time` option.

It's unfortunate that the `secondAttribute` property of `NSLayoutConstraint` is read-only. Otherwise, you could just create an outlet to the storyboard constraint, and just tweak that at `viewDidLoad` time.

Answer (score 0):

Use following code

```swift
let constraint = NSLayoutConstraint(
    item: myLabel,
    attribute: .bottom,
    relatedBy: relation,
    toItem: myView,
    attribute: .bottom,
    multiplier: 1,
    constant: constant
)
myLabel.addConstraint(constraint)
```